# What are <DCCReference> tags for in Delphi .dproj files?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I happened to notice a `<DCCReference>` tag that referenced a file that didn't even exist. What is the point of these tags? What would be the consequences of deleting them?

Comment: You delete them, and the ide adds them right back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thats the XML it uses to store what the project is.  If you add anything to the `dpr` file it changes the `dproj` to suit.  If you add a file to the project from the ide it changes both the `dpr` and the `dproj`.  You can delete the entry, its self repairing to some extent.  Also, a file does not need to be in here to be included in the compile.  If a unit has it in it's `uses` clause then it will be pulled in.

If it keeps coming back then remove the unit from the project in the ide.  If its not there then remove it from the dpr.

Finally 2007 has a bug where it can add multiple variations of a file name into the dproj.  You have to delete the offending ones manually.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not explain what is the purpose of that entry (as the author of the question asked).